# RuntimeError (can't create Java VM)

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, jvm, rjb

thanks to read my question.

I want to use rjb, twkorean gem. These are successfully installed

but I got error........

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 19ms
RuntimeError (can't create Java VM):
```

I had installed java-7-oracle

```
$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle

$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_80"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_80-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.80-b11, mixed mode)

$ ps aux | grep jvm
newstru+ 26483  0.0  0.0  11740   932 pts/0    R+   18:08   0:00 grep --color=auto jvm
```

Following code is my production envirnment (ubuntu 16.04).

I don't understand this error. I have no idea.

please, tell me any idea.

Answer (score 0):

You should check and post some logs to get more information about the problem. It could have many root causes:

1. The tool you are trying to use does not have permissions to execute
   java
2. The tool you are using cannot find the java executable. According to http://rjb.rubyforge.org/ you could try to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH to contain your $JAVA_HOME/bin folder.

In general, you should maybe try searching for (and reading) documentation about your tools first before posting to SO, and when posting, follow some basic rules: https://stackoverflow.com/tour